# how store Dynamic dropdown all value (Selected/Unselected) C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding a Dropdown dynamically. Now i need to catch all value (selected & Unselected) to pass through in a function.

This in my dropdown code.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVoucherTypes" cssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RedefineOldVoucherHistory"
                                AutoPostBack="true">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

How can i get all value with coma (,) separated ? like this (13,23,45,21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use in a method

```
var values = string.Join(",", ddlVoucherTypes.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like you want ?

```
        var values = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ddlVoucherTypes.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            values.Add(ddlVoucherTypes.Items[i].Value);
        }
        var result = string.Join(",", values);
```